# As3IsoLib: IsoBoxes in an Array

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm wanting to store four boxes in an array and iterate over all of them in a 'for' loop placing each at a different location. I'm using the isometric library As3IsoLib. Here is my code so far.

```
var BOX1:IsoBox = new IsoBox();
var BOX2:IsoBox = new IsoBox();

var myArray:Array = new Array(BOX1,BOX2);

for (var occr:IsoBox in myArray){
```

But I'm getting an error at my 'for' loop line which is

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type as3isolib.display.primitive:IsoBox.  isometric.as    /main/src   line 51 Flex Problem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
for (var occr:IsoBox in myArray){
```

Should be:

```
for each (var occr:IsoBox in myArray){
```

That will solve the error. This is happening because it is intended to loop over properties of an object, not indexes of an array. So there is a strange type requirement.

The "for each" loop is much better suited to looping over elements of an array.

Comment: I would like to +1 this answer but it is not 100% correct. In the "for (var occr:IsoBox in myArray)" loop it is trying to assign the KEY of the array to occr variable which is why you get a type casting error. In the for each "(var occr:IsoBox in myArray)" loop it is assigning the element of the specific iteration of the loop to the occr variable

Comment: @The_asMan read it again slowly I think he got it right, he's saying the first option is wrong, the second option is actually iterating over the elements as you say... think you're in agreement with what's posted here (I gave it the +1, think it's right on... though my guess is this has come up on SO before)